# Como puedo obterner un dato de una tabla html previamete poblada por una consulta para usar ese dato en otra consulta

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

actualmente me encuentro realizando una aplicación web para generar reportes, mi problemática es la siguiente, realizo una búsqueda por medio de un formulario, cuando este regresa respuesta la guardo en una tabla

TABLA:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO en el archivo html:

```
<form method="POST" class="col s12" id="frmBusqueda">
                                <div class="row col s7" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                    <p class = "col s3">Buscar por: </p>
                                    <div class="">
                                        <p>
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name ="usuario" vaule="usuario" id="checkUno" <?php ?>/>
                                                <span>Usuario</span> 
                                            </label>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="usuarioNombre" vaule="usuarioNombre" id="checkDos" <?php ?>/>
                                                <span>Nombre usuario</span> 
                                            </label>
                                        </p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s5 row" >
                                    <input id="busqueda" type="text" class="validate" name="busqueda" style="margin-top:10px;" />
                                    <label for="busqueda">Usuario o Nombre</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class ="row">
                                    <button class="col s2 btn btn-medium waves-effect indigo btnRedondo fontRobotoR" type="submit" name="btnEnviar" action="consultaUsuarios.php">Buscar
                                        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- se capturan los datos y se envian a consulta -->
                            <?php 
                                if (isset($_POST['btnEnviar'])) {

                                    //se obtienen valores
                                    $busqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];
                                    $usuario = "";
                                    $nombreUsuario = "";
                                    if (isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
                                        $usuario = "usuario";
                                    }else if(isset($_POST['usuarioNombre'])){
                                        $usuario = "usuarioNombre";
                                    } 
                                    $campo = "";
                                    if ($usuario == 'usuario') {
                                        $campo = "username";
                                    }else{
                                        $campo = "full_name";
                                    }


                                    $registros = usuarios($campo, $busqueda);

                                    $nRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($registros);

                                ?>
```

En esta tabla guardo la información de la respuesta:

```
<table class="bordered highlight centered responsive-table" id="tbaUno">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Usuario</th>
                                        <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
                                        <th>Organización</th>
                                        <th>Puesto</th>
                                        <th>Plantilla</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                if ($registros->num_rows) {
                                    foreach ($registros as $registro){
                                        ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="usuario" ><a href="" style="color: green;"><?php echo $registro['username']?></a></td>
                                        <td id="nombreCompleto" style="text-align: left;"><a href="" style="color: green;"><?php echo $registro['full_name']?></a></td>
                                        <td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $registro['organization']?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $registro['organizational_role']?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $registro['plantilla']?></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php  } 

                                    } 
                                 }
                            ?>
                                </tbody>

                            </table>
```

QUERY de la primera consulta:

```
function usuarios($campo, $busqueda){
include 'connection.php';
try {
    return $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT  a.user_id, username , full_name, organization, organizational_role, plantilla
    FROM guacamole_db.guacamole_user a
    WHERE $campo like '%$busqueda%' ORDER BY $campo");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error!!" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    return false;
}
```

}

Acá viene la pregunta, ¿como puedo obtener ese dato que aparece en verde para guardarlo en una variable y esa variable concatenara a otra consulta? la consulta es similar a la que anexé arriba en la función en donde **$idBusqueda guardaría el dato que esta en verde** y **$campo guardaría el dato que se uso en la primera consulta**, de antemano agradezco su ayuda compañeros.

QUERY de la segunda consulta en donde quiero recibir esas variable para usarlas en el query:

```
function infoUsuario($campo, $idBusqueda){
include 'conection.php';
try{
    return $conn->query("SELECT a.user_id, username , full_name, organization, organizational_role, b.connection_id, plantilla, c.connection_name
    FROM guacamole_db.guacamole_user a LEFT JOIN guacamole_db.guacamole_connection_permission b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    LEFT JOIN  guacamole_db.guacamole_connection c
    ON b.connection_id = c.connection_id
    WHERE $campo like '%$idBusqueda%'
    ORDER BY c.connection_name");

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error!!" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    return false;
}
```

}

ACTUALIZACIÓN
al realizar la implementación del método AJAX para obtener el dato requerido para la siguiente consulta, el resultado fue el siguiente.

**CÓDIGO DENTRO DE LOS TAG SCRIPT**

```
<script>
            function consultar(username){
                    data = {'username':username,
                            }
                    $.ajax({
                        data:  data,
                        url:   'consultaUsuarios.php',
                        type:  'POST',
                        success:  function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

**CÓDIGO PHP EN DONDE GUARDO EN VARIABLE EL DATO DE INTERES Y ENVIO A LA FUNCIÓN QUE CONTIENE EL QUERY**

```
<?php 

            if(isset($_POST['username'])){

                $idBusqueda = $_POST['username'];
                $campo = "";


                if(strlen($idBusqueda) > 7){
                    $campo = "full_name"; 
                }else{
                    $campo = "username";
                }

                echo "El dato que seleccionaste es: ".$idBusqueda."\n"."el campo es: ".$campo;

                $registrosC = infoUsuario($campo, $idBusqueda);

                $nRegistrosC = mysqli_num_rows($registrosC);
                //echo "numero de resultado: ".$nRegistrosC;   
        ?>
```

**FUNCIÓN DONDE SE RECIBEN LOS PARÁMETROS PARA LA CONSULTA**

```
function infoUsuario($campo, $idBusqueda){
include 'connection.php';
try{
    return $conn->query("SELECT a.user_id, username , full_name, organization, organizational_role, b.connection_id, plantilla, c.connection_name
    FROM guacamole_db.guacamole_user a LEFT JOIN guacamole_db.guacamole_connection_permission b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    LEFT JOIN  guacamole_db.guacamole_connection c
    ON b.connection_id = c.connection_id
    WHERE $campo like '%$idBusqueda%'
    ORDER BY c.connection_name");

}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error!!" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    return false;
}
```

}

**RESULTADO DEL LOG EN CONSOLA DEL NAVEGADOR EN DONDE LO MARCADO EN NEGRO ES LA RESPUESTA QUE ESTA EN BASE DE DATOS QUE SE AGREGA A LAS TABLAS QUE ACTUALMENTE NO SE MUESTRAN**

```
<script>

            function consultar(username){

                    data = {'username':username,

                            }

                    $.ajax({

                        data:  data,

                        url:   'consultaUsuarios.php',

                        type:  'POST',

                        success:  function (data) {

                        console.log(data);

                    }

                });

            }

        </script>



        **El dato que seleccionaste es: 1400599
        El campo es: username**

        <!-- se agrega la condicion para que aparesca al dar click en la seleccion de la tabla -->

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -50%;">

            <div class="col s5" style="position:absolute; top:39%;">

                <div class="card">

                    <div class="card-panel">

                        <div class="row">

                            <table class="bordered highlight  responsive-table" id="myTable">

                                <thead>

                                    <tr>

                                        <th class="fontRobotoR">Conexiones:</th>

                                    </tr>    

                                </thead>    

                                <tbody>

                                        <tr>

                                            **<td>ALBIS CNSIVope1</td>**

                                        </tr>

                                 </tbody>    

                            </table>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>   

            </div>



            <!-- Se agrega el total de conexiones -->

            <div class="col s5" style="margin-left: 50%;">

                <h2 class="header">Total de Conexiones</h2>

                <div class="card horizontal ">

                <div class="card-image">

                    <i class="large material-icons prefix" style="color: black">wifi</i>

                </div>

                <div class="card-stacked">

                    <div class="card-content center fontRobotoR">

                        <p>Total de conexiones</p>

                    </div>

                    <li class="divider"></li>

                    <div class = "row col s12">

                        <h4 style = "text-align: center; margin-bottom: -15px">**101**</h4> 

                    </div>

                                    </div>

            </div> 

        </div>

    </div>   

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente podrias hacer algo como esto, supondiendo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>nombre</td>
<td>Valor</td>
<td>CONSULTAR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>DIEGO AVILA</td>
<td>10.50</td>
<td><a href="miruta.php?username=diego">Factura</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>VALERIA PAREDES</td>
<td>25.50</td>
<td><a href="miruta.php?username=valeria">Factura</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>FERNANDA PAREDES</td>
<td>100.50</td>
<td><a href="miruta.php?username=fernanda">Factura</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Este es desde donde envio el username, para ello en el hipervinculo agrego algo asi:

```
<td id="usuario" ><a href="miruta.php?username=<?php echo $registro['username']?>" style="color: green;"><?php echo $registro['username']?></a></td>
```

y en tu archivo php recibes algo asi:

```
<?php
...
$username = $_GET['username'];
...
..?>
```

Este es el metodo GET... adaptalo a tus necesidades.

**Metodo Ajax - Nueva Edición **

supongamos la misma estructura html(table):

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>nombre</td>
<td>Valor</td>
<td>CONSULTAR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>DIEGO AVILA</td>
<td>10.50</td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="consultar('<?php echo $username; ?>');">Factura</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>VALERIA PAREDES</td>
<td>25.50</td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="consultar('<?php echo $username; ?>');">Factura</a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
function consultar(username){
   data = {'username':username}
    $.ajax({
       data:  data,
       url:   'mi_archivo.php',
       type:  'post',
       success:  function (data) {
        console.log(data);
       }
     });
}//end function consultar
```

ahora el archivo lo recibe por el metodo post:

```
<?php
...
$username = $_POST['username'];
...
...

?>
```

Espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, lo que necesito también es evitar el refresh de la página para no perder los datos que obtengo y guardo en la tabla con la primera consulta.

Comment: en este caso debes usar ajax..que es de Jquery debes incluirlo en tu html

Comment: Algún ejemplo que tengas para poder basarme en el?

Comment: @AlexisCaballero listo ya he editado mi respuesta espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!
hago la prueba y confirmo

Comment: Hola de nuevo Diego, realice el ejercicio como lo mencionaste en el ejemplo y efectivamente si funciono, el caso es de que lo que necesito solo lo imprime en el log de la consola del navegador, pero no se muestra nada en el navegador

Comment: en efecto es porque console muestra alli nose si editas tu pregunta y agregas lo que sale en console para poder editar mi respuesta y ayudarte..!!

Comment: De antemano agradezco todo tu apoyo Diego, ya actualice con las salidas del log y el código que implemente